# Importing between different versions of python

Tags: python, import, jupyter-notebook

I have a notebook in python 2 and a notebook in python 3. Code written in the notebook 2 is cannot be directly transfered to python 3 due to syntax differences. However, I do not want to import the code, I only want to import the final answer I got after running the code.

```
Notebook_A: Python 2

def func(x):
    print x
    return x

z = f(3) #z is now 3, I want to import the value 3.

Notebook_B: Python 3

from Notebook_A import z
    SyntaxError: missing parentheses in call to 'print'
```

Now I could go back to func and modify the code so that it matches python 3 syntax, but in the case that func is more complicated, I was wondering if there is a more general way. Is there a way to somehow just save the final value of a variable so that the notebook can forget about the code that generated the value?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need a data structure to old these informations, and defining protocols for handling this data structure.

For example common, well supported, data structures used in a Client/Server architecture are json(suggested)/XML you can also generate a .txt file with the result.

Just encode your results in python 2.x and decode them in python 3.y.